# Is there a way to detect a viewer's homepage in javascript?

Tags: javascript

Ideally I would like a cross browser solution.

Thanks!

Comment: Doubt it unless you have some sort of program installed on a user's Windows PC.

Comment: do you also want to peep in my bookmarks, stored passwords and proxy settings?

Comment: @just somebody - that wasn't part of the question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Nope, there's definitely no way. The user's home page is clearly part his own, private data, and having programmatic access to it would be a security nightmare.

Answer (score 2):

No, javascript which runs in a sandbox, don't have access to these kind of resources.

Read this article on

**[JavaScript Security](http://www.devarticles.com/c/a/JavaScript/JavaScript-Security/)**

> **JavaScript Security Models**
>
> The modern JavaScript security model
>   is based upon Java. In theory,
>   downloaded scripts are run by default
>   in a restricted “sandbox” environment
>   that isolates them from the rest of
>   the operating system. Scripts are
>   permitted access only to data in the
>   current document or closely related
>   documents (generally those from the
>   same site as the current document). No
>   access is granted to the local file
>   system, the memory space of other
>   running programs, or the operating
>   system’s networking layer. Containment
>   of this kind is designed to prevent
>   malfunctioning or malicious scripts
>   from wreaking havoc in the user’s
>   environment. The reality of the
>   situation, however, is that often
>   scripts are not contained as neatly as
>   one would hope. There are numerous
>   ways that a script can exercise power
>   beyond what you might expect, both by
>   design and by accident.
>
> The fundamental premise of browsers’
>   security models is that there is no
>   reason to trust randomly encountered
>   code such as that found on Web pages,
>   so JavaScript should be executed as if
>   it were hostile. Exceptions are made
>   for certain kinds of code, such as
>   that which comes from a trusted
>   source. Such code is allowed extended
>   capabilities, sometimes with the
>   consent of the user but often without
>   requiring explicit consent. In
>   addition, scripts can gain access to
>   otherwise privileged information in
>   other browser windows when the pages
>   come from related domains.